# How does Stealth work after using Bluff in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth

Bluff checks enable a creature to move unnoticed while moving stealthily, by creating a diversion, but the RAW is unclear because it states:

> This check, however, is made at a –10 penalty because you have to **move fast**.
>
> — *From the [Paizo PRD on Stealth](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/stealth.html).*

Does "move fast" means that the creature can move at full speed without an additional -5, as stated by RAW*?

*You can move up to half your normal speed and use Stealth at no penalty. When moving at a speed greater than half but less than your normal speed, you take a –5 penalty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

---

According to the [Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth) skill:

> When moving at a speed greater than half but less than your normal speed, you take a –5 penalty
>
> **Being Observed** If people are observing you using any of their senses (but typically sight), you can't use Stealth. Against most creatures, finding cover or concealment allows you to use Stealth. If your observers are momentarily distracted (such as by a Bluff check), you can attempt to use Stealth. While the others turn their attention from you, you can attempt a Stealth check if you can get to an unobserved place of some kind. This check, however, is made at a –10 penalty because you have to **move fast**.

This fast movement is to take advantage of the momentary distraction offered by the Bluff.  As it does not specify you are able to move your full speed without penalty, If you you chose to move over half of your speed, you will be making the check with a -15 penalty.

Comment: Yup!  Somewhat oddly for those without RAW-istic tendancies, moving *fast* in Pathfinder is completely different from moving *far*, and has nothing to do with your *speed*, which is a measure of the latter per round.