# Does the "fast stealth" skill reduce the penalty for stealthing from distracted observers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth

Part of the stealth rules from Paizo:

> If people are observing you using any of their senses (but typically sight), you can't use Stealth. Against most creatures, finding cover or concealment allows you to use Stealth. If your observers are momentarily distracted (such as by a Bluff check), you can attempt to use Stealth. While the others turn their attention from you, you can attempt a Stealth check if you can get to an unobserved place of some kind. This check, however, is made at a –10 penalty because you have to move fast.

Rogues can take a class talent, Fast Stealth:

> Benefit: This ability allows a rogue to move at full speed using the Stealth skill without penalty.

Would fast stealth reduce or eliminate the penalty in the first case?

A related [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67921/how-does-stealth-work-after-using-bluff-in-pathfinder) would seem to indicate that it wouldn't, but the name of the Fast Stealth feat makes me doubtful.

Answer (score 5):

### No.

Pathfinder tend to be very clear of what an ability does. As a rule of thumb, if doesn't say it does, it doesn't.
The ability says:

> This ability allows a rogue to ***move at full speed using the Stealth skill without penalty***.

In any moment it touches the subject of stealth at distracted targets, then the two matters are completely unrelated.

There's a distinct difference between going INTO stealth, and moving WHILE stealthing. The OP's example is clearly going INTO stealth, while the Fast Stealth skill is clearly about moving while already stealthing. Thanks to FvB to make the distinction even clearer.

Comment: My thought is that the -10 penalty for stealth from a distracted target is the same penalty as the one described in the Fast Stealth talent.  That is, both refer to the penalty for moving quickly while using stealth.

Comment: @JonathanBennett Not really. The Fast Stealth ability refers to the penalty you receive for moving faster than half your movement speed because is harder to move silently while moving faster. The other is a penalty due to the fact that you need to act quickly in the split moment of distraction of the person watching you. Two different things.

Comment: I feel there's a distinct difference between going INTO stealth, and moving WHILE stealthing. The OP's example is clearly going INTO stealth, while the Fast Stealth skill is clearly about moving while already stealthing.